# How to set default typeface of Android WebView

Tags: android, html, css, fonts, webview

How to set default typeface of a `WebView` in Android?

I know, I can use CSS fonts,
But how can I use it when I want to show an external URL like http://HossainCo.ir

For example, In dekstop firefox (currently I used) we can set default font to use when no other fonts used in CSS or HTML

So: I want to use "assets" font like "fonts/tohoma.ttf" when using `webView.loadUrl("hossainco.ir");`

Comment: Have you tried `set...FontFamily()`, like `setSerifFontFamily()`, on `WebSettings`?

Comment: Can you explain me more about your solution? I mean when I use it, it uses Typeface.SANS_SERIF?

Comment: I have no idea. I have not used those methods. However, they were the the only things I saw on `WebSettings` that might pertain to your question, which is why I mentioned them.